# C# Delete ListChanged event attached to Bindingsource

Tags: c#, function, events, bindingsource

I have a bindingsource as follows:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(dsOptions, "students");
```

I have added an event to it as follows:

```
bs.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler( (object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        lblCount.Text = bs.Count.ToString();
    });
```

Notice that I have added the event without having it in a separate function as the following line of code:

```
bs.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler( listCount);

private void listCount(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            lblCount.Text = bs.Count.ToString();
        }
```

But this is not what I am looking for.

How to remove the ListChanged event in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be very careful with this, as you can easily have bugs where you add the handler more than once, or worse, a growing amount of times.  This is really not what event handlers are meant for.  Generally if you need to disable an event handler it means you shouldn’t be using one (instead you should do something like update the Text when you set a wrapper property, or something more easily disabled).

But you asked; so you could do this:

```
var handler = new ListChangedEventHandler( (object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    lblCount.Text = bs.Count.ToString();
});
// keep handler in a member variable so you can refer to it later.

bs.ListChanged -= handler; // remove it just in case it’s been added before; there’s no harm, even if it hasn’t already been added.
bs.ListChanged += handler;

 ...

//later remove it
bs.ListChanged -= handler; // remove it

// do your logic where you want the handler disabled.

// now add it back.
bs.ListChanged -= handler; // remove it just in case it’s been added before; there’s no harm, even if it hasn’t already been added.
bs.ListChanged += handler;
```

Again, this is very bug-prone.  And it is hard to figure the bug out; there’s no simple way to check if you +=‘d more than once.  If you are not very careful you’ll accidentally add the handler more than once which could make the code setting the lblCount.Text get called many times over and could lead to your program getting progressively slower and slower, so I would recommend finding another way.

Comment: That is fair, but  as I mentioned in my question I need to remove the handler without adding a variable. I mean you added var handler = new ListChangedEventHandler ... But I need to refer to the event without having a variable or function

Comment: I don't understand the requirement of not adding a variable.  But you don't have to wrap the Action in a ListChangedEventHandler (which forces you to save it in a variable).  I.e. you could: bs.ListChanged += (object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) => lblCount.Text = bs.Count.ToString();  That way you could copy paste it to wherever you need to -= it.  But that's risky, and the behavior is not well-defined; -= could fail to match up the Actions.  A better way is to make a method void Handler(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) then call bs.ListChanged +=Handler; which would be safer to -=.